# S3sync not working

Tags: ubuntu, backup, amazon-s3

I managed to get s3sync to upload my test folder to Amazon S3 and can see it in the MWS Managment Console.

Downloading the data back to a test folder results in the following error message:

---

```
root@mybucketname:/var/s3sync# ./week_download.sh
s3Prefix backups/weekly
localPrefix /var/s3sync/testdown/weekly
s3TreeRecurse mybucketname backups/weekly
Creating new connection
Trying command list_bucket mybucketname prefix backups/weekly max-keys 200 delimiter / with 100 retries le
ft
Response code: 200
prefix found: /
s3TreeRecurse mybucketname backups/weekly /
Trying command list_bucket mybucketname prefix backups/weekly/ max-keys 200 delimiter / with 100 retries l
eft
Response code: 200
S3 item backups/weekly/
s3 node object init. Name: Path:backups/weekly Size:0 Tag:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e Date:Fri O
ct 29 14:21:53 UTC 2010
local node object init. Name: Path:/var/s3sync/testdown/weekly/ Size: Tag: Date:
source:
dest:
Update node
s3sync.rb:638:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /var/s3sync/testdown/weekly/.s3syncTemp (E
rrno::ENOENT)
from s3sync.rb:638:in `open'
from s3sync.rb:638:in `updateFrom'
from s3sync.rb:393:in `main'
from s3sync.rb:735
```

---

I am using the following download script:

---

```
#!/bin/bash
# script to download local directory upto s3
cd /var/s3sync/
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=nothing to see here
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=nothing to see here
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/var/s3sync/certs
ruby s3sync.rb -r -v -d --progress --make-dirs mybucket:backups/weekly /var/s3sync/testdown
# copy and modify line above for each additional folder to be synced
```

---

Any idea's? Does the download script need to download to the source of Amazon S3 i.e testup folder? Was hoping on the instance of a complete failure and the original folders won't exist that it would just download everything from me.

Note: changed my bucket names to "mybucketname" so that it is not public!

Comment: Is it possible for you to reformat the posting, so we could see the script clearly ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to download (GET) the bucket/prefix must be specified first and the local path second. To upload (PUT) the order is reversed with the path first and the bucket second. In your download example the bucket is specified second so it's actually trying to upload the "tesstup" directory.

http://s3.amazonaws.com/ServEdge_pub/s3sync/README.txt

Comment: Sorry, actually pasted my 'upload' script that works, instead of the download script that doesn't! Have edited my original post with actual download script.

Comment: Could be a bug in s3sync. Verify that /var/s3sync/testdown exists. mkdir -p /var/s3sync/testdown